# exclude a string from search in regex

Tags: regex, grep

I want to be able to search for anything between brackets, but excluding a certain string. e.g. I do not want to search for XXX but anything else is okay.

`<XXX>` does not match but `<XYZ>` `<YZ>` etc do match

I am unsure how to use a wildcard to search for the string between the brackets but excluding XXX. How would I go about doing this?

edit: I'm just talking about basic grep

Comment: What regex flavor is this? Does it support lookaheads/lookbehinds? Please tag your programming language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: `<(?!XXX>)[^>]*>`

Comment: **You can refer to it**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: 4castle's answer works when I try it on regexr.com, but doesn't seem to work when I run it on my machine.

Comment: @basil Read the duplicate question. Look at `grep` options; consider if `-E` is what you want.

Comment: I read the question posted. I feel it does not apply here, hence why I asked the question.  I have tried egrep as well, to no avail.

Comment: use `-P` option..`grep -P <(?!XXX>)[^>]*>`

Comment: rock321987's solution works.  -P is perl, right? I should be able to pipe this through perl right? I tried: **cat temp.txt | perl -pne 'if ($1 =~ /<(?!(XXX)>)[^>]*>/){ print $1;}'** but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Two expressions are necessary, one to match, one to exclude:

```
grep '<.*>' | grep -v '<XXX>'
```

If preferred, they can be put together into a single `sed` or `awk` script:

```
sed '/<.*>/!d;/<XXX>/d'
```

or

```
awk '/<.*>/&&!/<XXX>/'
```